# Unable to view Serial.print() for Arduino micro

Tags: arduino

Hi anyone knows why Serial.print() does not work for Arduino micro?

I tried this code

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); // initialization
  while (!Serial){}
   ;  

  Serial.println("Begin");
}
```

But nothing was shown on the serial monitor.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you actually write a valid code? You did not close your while block.

Comment: Srry I forgot to close the while block. corrected my code already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you meant:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  
  Serial.println("Begin");
}
```

and actually what you want is:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Begin");
}
```

because I think that `!Serial` is not a defined behaviour, as `Serial` is the instance for the serial communication. And calling the `not` operator on the `Serial` class may compile and work, but it will always return the same thing whether it is true or false. If it returns false, you will just end up blocking your arduino from doing anything else after that statement.

Though, basically, when you setup the serial communication, you can safely assume it is ready to communicate. Sometimes, you may need to delay a bit (about 3 seconds from my own experience), for the host computer to setup the device for every atmega32uX based arduinos, which is the case of the Micro and the Leonardo. If you don't add that delay of 3 seconds, the `Begin` statement will be printed by the Arduino, but you won't see it, as the computer did not reset the device up again *before* it gets printed.

To better understand what I mean try the following code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(10);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(9);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(8);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(7);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(6);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(5);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(4);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(3);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(2);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(1);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Begin");
}
```

if you open the serial monitor *very* early, you will only see the output starting from `7`.

HTH

Comment: "while (!Serial){};" replaces the 3s delay for U32's and USB arduino's. This is now a common practice. And can be left it for other none USB AVR's as the Serial is up immediately in those cases. So your first guess is correct. shannon's error was with the {'s as you pointed out.

Comment: I think zmo is correct as I tried to run the code with while(!Serial){}, 'begin' is not printed. I added a delay using delay(3000) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

For the Leandro, Micro, and any other boards using the Atmega32u4 microcontrollers, you'll need to be sure to set RTS and DTR high after connecting to the controller.  Here is some C# code I've used:

```
_port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_port.Open();
_port.RtsEnable = true;
_port.DtrEnable = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was listening for serial port and wait until the Arduino sent a string `Arduino is ready!`. Only after that I would send data over Serial port (in my case via USB).
A way to solve this is wait a few seconds before exchange messages with Serial. But in my usecase I needed it to communicate ASAP. So what I did was:

```
String READY_MSG = "Arduino is ready!";
bool isConnected = false;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
   while(!Serial){
       // Do nothing... Wait for serial connection
       isConnected  = false;
   }
   // If we were not connected, it means we need to greet with READY_MSG
   if(!isConnected ){
       isConnected = true;
       Serial.print(READY_MSG);
   }
   // We can safely communicate now!
}
```

Hope this helps someone!